# Superscripting, using unicode & Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, unicode

I am wanting to display numbers with their exponent, in an HTML canvas. Since context.fillText(...) does not support HTML tags I thought I would try using unicode. The result is not quite what I expected, since the digits 1-3 don't behave in the same manner as the other superscripted numerals. My code is as follows:

```
   // Only supports integers and will round any non-integers
   function superscriptNumber(intNumber) {
        var text = '';          
        var number = Math.round(intNumber);
        var supers = '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'.split('');
        if (intNumber === 0) {
            text = supers[0] ;
        } else {
            while (Math.floor(number) > 0) {
                digit = number % 10;
                number = Math.floor(number / 10);
                text =  supers[digit] + text;
            }        
        }
        return text;
   }
```

Then if I do

```
   var text = '10 '+ superscriptNumber(1265);
   ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
```

Then I see the 1 & 2 at the same level and 6 & 5 slightly superscripted to them. I am suspecting that his may be down to the font, which is treating them slightly differently (1,2,3 aren't in the same unicode range for some reason)? Is there a way to improve on my code, to ensure consistency across fonts?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a font/unicode support issue. You can go on trying to experiment with specific fonts, but I guess you just will need to print numbers with a smaller font size in a different location.

Comment: I just went through all the standard web fonts for a windows machine and the is no consistency. Some only have 1,2,3 with the others numbers from another font (related in the same family), some are missing the other numbers and some have most the numbers but missing a few, and some have all the superscript numbers. Your best bet is to write your own fillText function and do the superscript yourself.